# Different scaling for different groups in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset contains different groups and normalized value which I created based on GDP. Normalised column contains a scale between 0 to 1 for every group. I want to rescale this value like, group A (0 to 10), group B (11 to 30), group C (31 to 50), and group D (51 to 100) in python.

Here is dataset:

```
Year    GDP  Group  Normalised
1970    84684   A   0.000000
1971    95806   A   0.029729
1972    106868  A   0.059298
1973    120720  A   0.096325
1974    139760  A   0.147219
1975    160477  A   0.202595
1976    182173  A   0.260589
1977    205919  A   0.324062
1978    222396  A   0.368106
1979    237848  A   0.409409
1980    264619  A   0.480968
1981    301452  A   0.579423
1982    336748  A   0.673770
1983    370430  A   0.763802
1984    409163  A   0.867336
1985    458794  A   1.000000
1986    515505  B   0.000000
1987    571608  B   0.130155
1988    606744  B   0.211669
1989    619600  B   0.241494
1990    639732  B   0.288199
1991    670016  B   0.358456
1992    697418  B   0.422027
1993    731043  B   0.500035
1994    769888  B   0.590153
1995    828636  B   0.726445
1996    876411  B   0.837280
1997    946551  B   1.000000
1998    1020061 C   0.000000
1999    1074489 C   0.057531
2000    1144839 C   0.131892
2001    1211783 C   0.202653
2002    1258692 C   0.252236
2003    1308153 C   0.304517
2004    1407892 C   0.409943
2005    1514364 C   0.522485
2006    1661699 C   0.678221
2007    1830997 C   0.857171
2008    1946700 C   0.979471
2009    1966122 C   1.000000
2010    2077604 D   0.000000
2011    2161617 D   0.116603
2012    2298445 D   0.306508
2013    2423242 D   0.479716
2014    2539596 D   0.641205
2015    2621032 D   0.754231
2016    2712752 D   0.881530
2017    2798110 D   1.000000
```

I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this? It certainly can be done, but if you are simply trying to visualize the different groups there may be better ways to do it.

Comment: Since the new scale for each group is not same , I think you may need for loop here

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: Please add more hints on what you want to accomplish. With this much info I would recommend using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)  which divides your data into buckets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use np.select() as shown below.

```
import numpy as np

a0 = [0, 11, 31, 51]
a1 = [10, 19, 19, 49]

conditions = [
    (df['Group'] == 'A'),
    (df['Group'] == 'B'),
    (df['Group'] == 'C'),
    (df['Group'] == 'D')
] 

df['a0'] = np.select(conditions, a0)
df['a1'] = np.select(conditions, a1)
df['Rescaled'] = df['Normalised'].multiply(df['a1']).add(df['a0'])
```